# Wordpress: Remove 'uncategorized' upon theme activation

Tags: wordpress, function, categories

Is there a way to remove the default 'uncategorized' category (from categories in Wordpress admin) upon activating my theme?

This will have to go in functions.php obviously.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have at least one other category to set as the default, you should be able to go to Settings>>Writing and change the default post category to one of your other categories. After doing this you should be able to delete Uncategorized by going to Posts>>Categories and deleting it there.

You can also change the Uncategorized default category by adding this to functions.php:

```
// Uncategorized ID is always 1
wp_update_term(1, 'category', array(
    'name' => 'hello',
    'slug' => 'hello', 
    'description' => 'hi'
));
```

as shown in this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83415/remove-rename-uncategorized-category-in-wordpress

[More info on wp_update_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term)

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that, but I'm trying to remove it upon theme activation. There's a good reason for it which I won't bore you with :-)

Comment: Do you want the new theme to have no default category, or do you just want to change the default category prior to theme activation?

Comment: I want the new theme to have no default category. So, if someone was to create a new post and not choose a category, then that post would simply not have a category (instead of being 'uncategorized').

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I misunderstood your question. It seems as if all posts would need to have a category assignment for database storage/reference. This answer seems to suggest that what you're trying to do is impossible: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58144/deleting-default-category-in-wordpress but you've probably already seen that. Maybe you could just rename the category to '.' or something to hide it? Good luck finding a solution! :)

Comment: @PHPnoob I am sorry, but why can´t you use this method with `add_action("after_switch_theme", "update_terms", 10 ,  2);` - the answer Sean Henderson gave is valid as per your original question. A post must have a category and the only thing you can do is change its name . I see no reason for posts not to have categories . But you can delete them all and create a custom post type with no categories ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wp_delete_category function

```
<?php wp_delete_category( $cat_ID ) ?>
```

But you need at least 1 category in WordPress, so as long as you're create extra ones before hand you should be ok.

wp_delete_category reference page:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_category

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'remove_uncategorized_category' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'remove_uncategorized_category' );

function remove_uncategorized_category( $args ) {
  $uncategorized = get_option( 'default_product_cat' );
  $args['exclude'] = $uncategorized;
  return $args;
}
```